# Not sure about this translation

Tags: traducción

Tengo problemas con esta frase: "Yo solo copio". Mis intentos son:

- I just copy
- I only copy
- I copy

De la misma forma, con esta frase: "Yo nunca leo nada".

- I never read anything
- I never read
- I never read a thing

No hay contexto, son frases sueltas. Sería como una especie de característica de la persona (*Yo solo copio. Él bebe. Y ese otro nunca lee*).

En ambos casos, mis apuestas más seguras serían las primeras, pero tengo dudas. Gracias.

Comment: un poco off topic, en todo caso este en sitio te ayudarian con traducciones del ingles al español, despues de mostrar un esfuerzo.

Comment: Tu pregunta no encaja con este sitio ya que estás buscando una traducción al inglés. Este sitio trata sobre el español/castellano. Puedes leer más en el [FAQ].

Answer (score 0):

La traducción no es un tema que sea fácil. Para el primer caso, **Yo sólo copio**, se necesitaría un poco más de contexto, puesto que hay una ligera diferencia entre *just* y *only*.

Para la segunda frase, probablemente la primera opción sea la más correcta, tal vez *I never read a thing* sea un poco coloquial.